# GitBlit add a hook

Tags: groovy, gitlab, githooks, gitblit

I have a GitBlit instance on a windows server, and i want to set a [hook](http://gitblit.com/setup_hooks.html) on post receive callback to start a gitlab ci pipeline on another server.

I already have set a GitlabCi trigger who works well, but my hook doesn't. Here is `build-gitlab-ci.groovy` file :

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand.Result
import org.slf4j.Logger

logger.info("Gitlab-CI hook triggered by ${user.username} for ${repository.name}")

// POST :
def sendPostRequest(urlString, paramString) {
    def url = new URL(urlString)
    def conn = url.openConnection()
    conn.setDoOutput(true)
    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())

    writer.write(paramString)
    writer.flush()
    String line
    def reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        println line
    }
    writer.close()
    reader.close()
}
sendPostRequest("https://xxxxx/api/v4/projects/1/trigger/pipeline", "token=xxxxxxxx&ref=master")
```

The project configuration :

[image]

Moreover, i don't know where `logger.info` write the log, so i don't know if my script was executed well. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, it was a SSL self-certificate problem. I added this code to ignore it :

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand.Result
import org.slf4j.Logger

logger.info("Gitlab-CI hook triggered by ${user.username} for ${repository.name}")

def nullTrustManager = [
    checkClientTrusted: { chain, authType ->  },
    checkServerTrusted: { chain, authType ->  },
    getAcceptedIssuers: { null }
]

def nullHostnameVerifier = [
    verify: { hostname, session -> hostname.startsWith('yuml.me')}
]

javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
sc.init(null, [nullTrustManager as  javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager] as  javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager[], null)
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(nullHostnameVerifier as javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier)

def url = new URL("https://xxxx/api/v4/projects/{idProject}/trigger/pipeline")
def conn = url.openConnection()
conn.setDoOutput(true)
def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())

writer.write("token={token}&ref={branch}")
writer.flush()
String line
def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    println line
}
writer.close()
reader.close()
```

And I identified the error checking the logs in `E:\gitblit-1.7.1\logs\gitblit-stdout.{date}.log`.

> NB : `stdout` file date can be very old. Gitblit doesn't create a file per day. Mine had a name expired 4 months ago.